# Why is Angular sanitizing the following code? style="margin-left: 30px"

Tags: html, css, angular, sanitization, sanitize

It's not really a problem because Chrome executes it anyway but I'm just curious why it detects

```
style="margin-left: 30px"
```

as potentially harmful.

It's just a style property on a primeNG-Button element.

```
<p-button icon="pi pi-check" iconPos="right" label="change" style="margin-left: 30px" (click)="submit()"></p-button>
```

I tried to use the [style]-Property but with similar results.

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/warning/DangerousStyleAttr.html this may help you

Comment: See also https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#rule-4---css-escape-and-strictly-validate-before-inserting-untrusted-data-into-html-style-property-values

Comment: Your examples are *valid HTML* and not subject to any warnings or errors from Angular or Chrome. So I don't understand what the question is here. Please update your question with a reproducible example of your problem, and explain the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Since CSS rules can cause browsers to fetch content via a URL, `style` tags are vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Try changing the style tag to this and run it in IE:

`style="background-image: url(javascript:alert('XSS'))"`